# SQL query returns 0 rows for multiple AND conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to classify these 2 rows based on last 3 columns by AND/OR the following details using filters:
[image]

Now The table structure as I am using needs multiple JOIN conditions:

**1.m_recipient**
[image]
sample data(m_recipient):
[image]

**2.m_invites_recipient**
[image]
sample data(m_invites_recipient):

[image]

**3.m_custom_field_values**
[image]
sample data(m_custom_field_values):
[image]

Now for example when I try to get the user whose value is rinnegan = yes and sharingan = no, the result is empty row(Answer should be first row. Whereas If I try to use rinnegan = yes or sharingan = no then I am getting both rows.

SQL query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT m_recipient.id, m_recipient.sd_recipient_id, 
  m_recipient.campaign_id, m_recipient.user_id, m_recipient.userid, 
  m_recipient.first_name, m_recipient.last_name, m_recipient.email, 
  m_recipient.survey_link, m_recipient.unsubscribe 
FROM m_invites_recipient 
JOIN m_recipient ON m_recipient.id = m_invites_recipient.m_recipient_sd_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN m_custom_field_values ON m_custom_field_values.related_to_id = m_recipient.id 
WHERE m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
  AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0  
  AND ( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "rinnegan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "yes" 
    AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 )  
  AND ( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "sharingan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "no" 
    AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 )
```

Comment: Seems correct to me,that`s what OR does.

Comment: But for AND its not working @Mihai

Comment: how it will be possible rinnegan and sharingan for the same row?

Comment: Well naturally it doesn't work with AND. There's no way you can ever have a row where all of `( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "rinnegan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "yes" 
    AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 )` is true **AND** all of `( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "sharingan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "no" 
    AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 ) ` is true.It's impossible to match both sets of criteria, they're contradictory, it's simple logic

Comment: Even just the first field causes a problem - you can't have a row where custom_field_name = "rinnegan" AND custom_field_name = "sharingan". It's trivially obvious that the field can't have both values at the same time. It's not 100% clear what you want to achieve but I have written an answer which suggests one possibility. It doesn't help that you haven't given us any sample data from the actual tables.

Comment: change it to AND m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name IN("sharingan", "rinnegan")

Comment: column designed with `'yes'` and `'no'` is on of most "original" i have ever seen. Is this real, or My Admin 'beautifuy" database?

Comment: Um, that isn't a LEFT JOIN. Just sayin'

Comment: based on your sample data, due to `JOIN m_recipient ON m_recipient.id = m_invites_recipient.m_recipient_sd_id` you should only ever get the first row from m_recipient returned anyway, regardless of the other clauses...are there more rows in m_invites_recipient which you haven't shown us? Apart from that, the basic problem is you're trying to look at data in more than one row simultaneously, which SQL is not really designed for. You perhaps need to join to m_custom_field_values twice, once for each possible custom field name value. Then you'll get all the data in one row instead of two.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ADyson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ADyson said you can use multiple join like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT m_recipient.id, 
m_recipient.sd_recipient_id, 
m_recipient.campaign_id, 
m_recipient.user_id, 
m_recipient.userid, 
m_recipient.first_name, 
m_recipient.last_name, 
m_recipient.email, 
m_recipient.survey_link, 
m_recipient.unsubscribe 
FROM   m_invites_recipient 
   JOIN m_recipient 
     ON m_recipient.id = m_invites_recipient.m_recipient_sd_id 
   JOIN m_custom_field_values AS a0 
     ON a0.related_to_id = m_recipient.id 
   JOIN m_custom_field_values AS a1 
     ON a1.related_to_id = m_recipient.id 
WHERE  m_invites_recipient.last_opened = 0 
   AND m_invites_recipient.last_clicked = 0 
   AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    OR ( a0.custom_field_name = "sharingan" 
         AND a0.value = "no" 
         AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
         AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 ) 
    OR ( a1.custom_field_name = "rinnegan" 
         AND a1.value = "yes" 
         AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
         AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 )
```

For example, to compare more than two rows you just need to add one more JOIN

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to match rows with either match all the first set of bracketed criteria, or match all the second set of bracketed criteria?

If so then you can simply do this:

```
( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "rinnegan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "yes" 
    AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 )  
  OR                             #note the change from AND to OR here
( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "sharingan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "no" 
    AND m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
    AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0 )
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is the logic in your WHERE condition. It can be rewritten as the following:

```
WHERE m_invites_recipient.m_invites_id = 6 
  AND m_recipient.unsubscribe = 0  
  AND ( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "rinnegan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "yes")  
  AND ( m_custom_field_values.custom_field_name = "sharingan" 
    AND m_custom_field_values.value = "no")
```

Which obviously will return no rows, since no rows are equal to both "rinnegan" **AND** "sharingan".

**EDIT**:

The problem here is that you are trying to use data from multiple rows in your where condition, which can prove tricky. There may be a more elegant way to do this, but a possible solution to do this is to use sub-queries to find the 'answers' to the questions. Something like the following:

```
WITH 
rinneganQuery AS (
    SELECT value AS rinneganAnswer, related_to_id FROM m_custom_field_values 
    WHERE custom_field_name = 'rinnegan'
),
sharinganQuery AS (
    SELECT value AS sharinganAnswer, related_to_id FROM m_custom_field_values 
    WHERE custom_field_name = 'sharingan'
)

SELECT DISTINCT inv.id, inv.sd_recipient_id, 
  inv.campaign_id, inv.user_id, inv.userid, 
  inv.first_name, inv.last_name, inv.email, 
  inv.survey_link, inv.unsubscribe 
FROM m_invites_recipient inv
INNER JOIN m_recipient rec ON inv.m_recipient_sd_id = rec.id 
INNER JOIN rinneganQuery rq ON inv.m_recipient_sd_id = rq.related_to_id
INNER JOIN sharinganAnswer sq ON inv.m_recipient_sd_id = sq.related_to_id
WHERE inv.m_invites_id = 6 
  AND rec.unsubscribe = 0
  AND rq.rinneganAnswer = 'yes'
  AND sq.sharinganAnswer = 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.id
              , r.sd_recipient_id
              , r.campaign_id
              , r.user_id
              , r.userid
              , r.first_name
              , r.last_name
              , r.email
              , r.survey_link
              , r.unsubscribe 
           FROM m_invites_recipient i
           JOIN r 
             ON r.id = i.m_recipient_sd_id 
           JOIN m_custom_field_values v
             ON v.related_to_id = r.id 
          WHERE i.m_invites_id = 6 
            AND r.unsubscribe = 0  
            AND 
                ( v.custom_field_name = "rinnegan" 
              AND v.value = "yes" 
              AND i.m_invites_id = 6 
              AND r.unsubscribe = 0
                )
             OR 
                ( v.custom_field_name = "sharingan" 
              AND v.value = "no" 
              AND i.m_invites_id = 6 
              AND r.unsubscribe = 0 
                );
```